# Load Spring-Boot application.yaml file based on system environment variables

Tags: java, spring

My friend and I are working on a Spring-Boot application. Right now when running `mvn spring-boot:run`, Spring-Boot, by default, loads the application.yaml file under `src/main/resources/config`.

My friend and I have a system environment variable called 'DEV' setup. So in the command line, typing `echo $DEV` would return `dev.friend` or `dev.mmp`.

Under `src/main/resources/config`, we want to add the directories `/dev/friend` and `/dev/mmp`. And within these directories, there will be a specific `application.yaml` file.

So now we have this:

- src

  - main

    - resources

      - config

        - application.yaml
        - dev

          - friend

            - application.yaml
          - mmp

            - application.yaml

How can we set up Spring configurations using only annotations (we want to avoid writing anymore xml other than `pom.xml`) such that when we run `mvn spring-boot:run` the `application.yaml` file loaded will be based on the `DEV` environment variable of the current computer.

We know that we can do the following to create a FileSystemResource from the `DEV` variable:

```
public FileSystemResource configLoader() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder path;
    URL propertiesURL;
    String hostName = System.getenv("DEV");
    path = new StringBuilder("/config");
    if (hostName != null && !hostName.isEmpty()) {
        String[] hostNameParts = hostName.split("\\.");
        for (String s : hostNameParts) {
            path.append('/').append(s);
        }
    }
    path.append('/').append("application.yaml");
    propertiesURL = getClass().getResource(path.toString());
    return new FileSystemResource(propertiesURL.getFile());
}
```

But we have no idea how to proceed, this is our first Spring project. Google searches only lead to examples loading a default `application.yaml` (which we already have) located under `config/` and that's not what we want. We want to extend this so that our staging server will have its own `DEV` system variable and we can just add another directory under config (like above) with an `application.yaml` file.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `application.yml` files, **profile-specific** yamls can also be defined using the naming convention `application-{profile}.yml`. So, it's better to define three yaml configs as following: `application.yml`, `application-devfriend.yml` and `application-devmmp.yml`.

If you do not activate any profile, by default `application.yml` will be loaded. If you activate `devfriend` profile, config values from `application-devfriend.yml` would override the `application.yml` ones. In order to activate one profile, use `spring.profiles.active` property. For example:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=devfriend yourapp.jar
```

You can also add a environment variable for `spring-profiles-active`.

**Update:** If you insist to use `DEV` environment variable for switching between profiles, add this in your `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${dev}
```

Comment: Having profile-specific 'named' yamls defeats the purpose of setting up environment variables. I understand that I can set spring.config.name, spring.config.location and spring.profiles.active from the command line, but that is not the purpose of my question. Companies that I interned at used environment variables to determine which config settings to apply, whether it was a development machine or a production server. This can be easily done in Node.js, but we chose Spring-Boot for specific reasons and we are trying to solve the problem mentioned in this post.

Comment: How? I don't get it. why profile specific configs defeat that?

Comment: You can easily switch between profiles with env vars. isn't that what you wanted in first place?

Comment: Yes, we want to switch profiles, without doing it from the command line. When I run 'mvn spring-boot:run' it should recognize that I am on a different host computer via the 'DEV' variable and then apply the settings from the correct directory.

Comment: You can achieve the same with `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env var

Comment: If you insists to use `DEV` env var, add `spring:profiles:active:${dev}` in your `application.yml`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = {"yourProperties"}) //create this path as a String above
```

to specify the location, which Spring Boot will load from a config class.

More here: [Spring External Config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Alternatively, in command line you can use property to mention an additional boot configuration file:

```
--spring.config.name="file:/path/to/application.yaml"
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of a config class?

Comment: yes, so you can use this line of code: String hostName = System.getenv("DEV"); to get env variable and create String, which you will use in @ConfigurationProperties. Normally, I will suggest to use dispatcher.xml file to fetch env.

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to set spring.config.location to the path of the desired application.yaml file inside the Spring Boot application.